# Catching sql error while running ant task using ij tool on derby

Tags: ant, derby

This is my ant task

```
<target name="reset-derby-db" depends="clean-derby-db">
    <java fork="true" classname="org.apache.derby.tools.ij" classpathref="derbylibraries">
        <sysproperty key="ij.connection.bwfla" value="jdbc:derby:${derby.db.dir};create=true"/>
        <arg value="${derby.sql.dir}/derby.sql"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

While running SQL files there could be some errors. I want to catch those errors in ant script.

Error looks like something like this

`ERROR 42X94: TYPE 'TEXT' does not exist.`

Errors are something strange and should be avoided, but just want to show user that there is an error, for this reason I want to catch the error and fail the ant task.

Comment: Have you tried failonerror? http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html

Comment: The ANT SQL task is another option. has an "onerror" attribute. See: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html

Comment: Since the task is Java I can use only failonerror. but no success, by using this attribute. As I am using IJ tool ant is not able to catch error.